# Increase timeout duration using CloseableHttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, timeoutexception

We have an application where we do some internal http calls to a REST API to fetch the data. But some requests are taking longer than expected so I am trying to increase the timeout duration. I tried below things :

RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(30 * 1000).build();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();

But this doesn't solve my issue. This solution works only for the first time. But when I re run this request I get the timeout exception. Can anyone help me with this.

Below is the stack trace

HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT [Content-Length: 0, Connection: keep-alive] [Content-Length: 0,Chunked: false]}

Comment: That's not a stack trace.

Comment: This is the only response I get from the Server. Server meaning I am accessing a REST API to get the data. Let me know if I am not clear

Answer (score 0):

You should also set socketTimeout (with setSocketTimeout() method).

Comment: I tried this too. But it didn't work. Your help is greatly apreciated :)

Comment: Could you add here full stack trace of your exception?

Comment: I added stacktrace to my question. Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT is timeout on server. Is it your REST API service or external?  Could you look deeply on server logs and identify the reason of timeout from the server side?

Comment: I also see, that by default RequestConfig timeouts are set to -1, it's mean infinite timeout. So, I think that it's not problem in your client
`this.connectionRequestTimeout = -1; this.connectTimeout = -1;this.socketTimeout = -1;`

Comment: I was wrong about -1 value: "A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout. A negative value is interpreted as undefined (system default)." If system default is not defined, timeout would be infinite. I suggest try to make http request with some console utilits (like [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html)) to clearly identify, that server returns 504 not only for your client.

Comment: Thanks for taking time Alexander. I will try curl request and will let you know. Actually I used postman to run the requests. Do you think using curl result might be different? Once again appreciate your time.

Comment: I tried the curl Request. I dont see any response on my terminal. Can you please help me.

Comment: Try  `curl -v` for diagnostic. Could you write full curl request and result here?

Comment: curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"BusinessStatus": ["HEADQUARTER", "SINGLE LOC"], "ResourceType": "Core", "LocationSalesVolumeRange": ["1-500000"], "LocationEmployeesSizeRange": ["1-4"], "RequestType": "Company", "Limit": 2000, "Offset": 92000, "PrimarySicList": ["811103"]}' http://localhost:8090/companies/search                                                                This is the request. I dont see any response.

Comment: Add `-v` flag to look at full response from your server (there should be response headers, http status code and etc). May be your server return empty response for this request. Could you copy here result of request with `-v` flag?

Comment: Alexander, Below is the response from curl if I add the -v tag                              -------------     curl 7.51.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.0) libcurl/7.51.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.8
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets